# Split birthdate in "YYYY" ,"MM" , "DD" & later Replace '-' with '/' in mulesoft

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component

I have 2 conditions as follows-:

1) Split the birthdate yyyy/mm/dd in yyyy mm dd and map them all in individual fields.
2) Convert yyyy-mm-dd in yyyy/mm/dd.

All these has to be done in datamapper in mulesoft. DO we have any other option or data mapper is best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the functions below when mapping a field on datamapper

#### For #1:

If the format is yyyy/MM/dd, you could just use "`substring()`" to get individual values.
eg.

```
input.departureDateStr.substring(0,4); // for YYYY
input.departureDateStr.substring(5,7); // for MM
input.departureDateStr.substring(8,10); // for dd
```

#### For #2:

For date conversions - date from/to string.

1. date2str(Date,String);
   input is a Date object
   output is a String

eg.

```
date2str(input.departureDate, 'yyyy/MM/dd')
```

2. str2date(String,String)
   input is a String
   output is a Date

eg.

```
str2date(input.departureDateStr, 'yyyy-MM-dd')
```

If you are converting a date in String to another String, probably you could do this.

```
// converts yyyy-MM-dd to yyyy/MM/dd
date2str(str2date(input.departureDateStr, 'yyyy-MM-dd'), 'yyyy/MM/dd')
```

Comment: Splitting of date Not working for me.. :-( exception: payload is of type string.

Comment: Maybe the input is not a String. Could you share the input schema and which field? If it is a Date object, you could convert that to String first using the date2str() function

Comment: output.rC_Bios__Birth_Day__c = input.birthDate.substring(8,10);
output.rC_Bios__Birth_Month__c = input.birthDate.substring(5,7);
output.rC_Bios__Birth_Year__c = input.birthDate.substring(0,4);

This is what I did, and the type of birthdate is string.

Comment: Looks correct to me. Please share the exception on logs.